# What is the difference between foo(int arr[]) and foo(int arr[10])?

Tags: c, function

Is there any difference between two function in C?

```
void f1(int arr[]) {    
//some code...  
}
void f2(int arr[10]) {
//some code
}
```

What will be the size of first array in f1 function?

Comment: There is no difference, except that in the second case it's somewhat self-documenting. `arr` decays to a pointer either way.

Comment: Well, you can do some testing, try to `printf("sizeof arr == %d\n", sizeof arr);` and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any difference between two function in c?

No difference here. Both will be interpreted as `int *arr` by the compiler as arrays are converted to a pointer to its first element when used as a function parameter.

> what will be the size of first array in f1 function?

Strictly speaking, there is no array here. Its only pointer to an `int`. If you will use `sizeof(arr)`, then you will get the value equal to `sizeof(int *)`.

The array size in parameters are needed when the type of parameter is a pointer to an array. in this case you need to have specify the size of array as each size makes the pointer to point to different type.

```
void f3(int (*arr)[10]); // Expects a pointer to an array of 10 int
```

Comment: which one will be the best practice void f1(int arr[10]) or void f2(int arr[]) or void f3(int (*arr)([10])) ?

Comment: Its matter of choice, but `f3(int (*arr)([10]))` is entirely different and you can't use in place of ` f1(int arr[10])` ( or ` f2(int arr[])` ).

Comment: how  f3(int (*arr)([10]))  is  different from other two ?

Comment: In `f3`, `arr` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int` while in other two its a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

When an array is passed to a function, it decays into a pointer to the first element of the array.

So this:

```
void f1(int arr[])
```

And this:

```
void f1(int arr[10])
```

And this:

```
void f1(int *arr)
```

Are all equivalent.

In fact if you passed `int a[20]` to a function declared to take `int arr[10]`, gcc won't complain.

Comment: Importantly, if you pass `int a[5]` to a function declared to take `int arr[10]` then the compiler *still* won't complain.  At most, the explicit dimension is advice to programmers about what the function expects.  It will not be enforced by a conforming compiler.

Comment: To be pedantic, an array expression is converted to a pointer expression *any time the array expression appears* (not just when passed as a function parameter) unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array in a declaration.